# При загрузке картинки через https отсутсвует header | Java

Tags: java, http, mime-type

У меня есть код для поиска расширения из header. Выполняется такой код:

```
URL document = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) document.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            String mimeType = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            MimeEntry mimeEntry = mimeTypes.find(mimeType.replaceAll(";.*", ""));
```

Если на вход приходит ссылка с http, то определяется расширение image/jpeg, а вот с https - null.

Один общий вопрос: как это можно исправить с минимальным количеством действий, и объясните почему так происходит.

---

**upd. Проблема была отложена, но она снова всплыла.**

Пример ссылок, которые приходят:
1)https://hubermedia.tourdata.at/media/display/original/8f97b6bad434b9645173d52e4766ba64/cover-film-kunststoff_neu.jpg

2)https://hubermedia.tourdata.at/media/display/original/a1b67da12e4d71886fec50b5d745d1f5/20180120_144200.jpg

3)https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/5/6c/les-zima-reka-iaponiia-dom-derevia-zdanie.jpg

текущий код не изменился, попробовал добавлять https вместо http - результат один и тот же - mimeType = null.

В логах есть ошибка:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
```

Comment: Для начала проверьте что отдает сайт =) может проблема не у вас?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков с сайтом всё хорошо, проверено, скрытая механика именно здесь

Comment: Пощупал ваши ссылки - `null` выскочил только на третьей. Увеличил таймаут до 2000 - как рукой сняло. Попробовал уменьшить до 500 - все три `null`. Наверное вы не учли, что защищённый коннект устанавливается дольше, чем открытый.

Comment: @woesss Вы через дебаг проверяли? Я сейчас выставил до 10.000, но всё также падает null.

Comment: Для определения расширения файла (как и его имени) можно еще посмотреть в сторону заголовка `content-disposition`. К примеру, для 2й ссылки он у вас такой: `content-disposition: filename="5a71f83a485c5_f240734.jpg"; filename*=UTF-8''5a71f83a485c5_f240734.jpg`. Однако, этот заголовок может быть не всегда представлен в ответе сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело, скорее всего в том, что Java не может по какой-то причине проверить сертификат сайта (скорее всего, надо добавить сертификат удостоверяющего центра в список доверенных сертификатов).
А `null` вы получаете потому что запрос реально ничего не возвращает и умирает с ошибкой - попробуйте добавить в код `System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());` и получите уже реальную ошибку `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.
Как я написал выше, она лечится или добавлением корневого сертификата в список доверенных, либо апдейтом JDK/JRE до последней версии (там, возможно, нужный сертификат уже добавлен по умолчанию).

**UPDATE:** Есть ещё один, **небезопасный вариант** - доверять всем сертификатам. Как-говорится, делайте на свой страх и риск:

```
URL document = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) document.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
       if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllCertsManager() }, new SecureRandom());
            ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        }
```

И код TrustAllCertsManager:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;

public class TrustAllCertsManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager implements TrustManager {

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return new X509Certificate[0];
}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType, final Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType, final SSLEngine engine) throws CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType, final Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType, final SSLEngine engine) throws CertificateException {

}

}
```

Comment: Где взять корневой сертификат?

Comment: @Lancelot на английском - https://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website  
на русском - в двух словах - откройте "проблемную" ссылку, нажмите на замочек, там будет надпись "Сертификат".  
Жмите на него, потом на закладку Certification Path, выбираете самый верхний, View Certificate. Потом идёте в Details -> Copy to file.. и экспортируете в der формат...
Ну или использовать openssl.  
Кстати, первая ссылка из Вашего списка нормально работает на JDK 1.8_201 - так что, возможно проще будет запустить Ваш код на этой версии

Comment: Ссылки всегда разные, не получится думаю. Openssl стоит. Версия на сервере - 1.7.0.19

Comment: Просто в апдейтах, они добавляют новые сертификаты для популярных удостоверяющих центров, так что, в теории, должно бы работать в 99% случаев. Если на сервере возможно обновиться до последней бесплатной версии 1.8, я бы так сделал. Если нет - придется отлавливать все сертификаты и добавлять их ручками

Comment: для openssl - https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file

Comment: openssl свои адрес и порт вводить или тоже каждой картинки?

Comment: каждой картинки. но, я думаю, лучше сначала попробовать на одной

Comment: @Lancelot, я ещё добавил в ответ небезопасный метод, который доверяет всем сертификатам

Comment: С TrustManager - это текущее решение, в виде временной подпорки уже стоит и оно работает. Но мне был хотелось разобраться с сертификатами, как их засетать можно. Нашёл на оригинальном sof эту проблему, там она намного популярнее, пока что результата 0.

Comment: Там ничего особо сложного - скачиваешь корневой сертификат и при помощи keytool добавляешь в cacerts файл JDK, обычно он находится в директории jre\lib\security. https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4085.html

Comment: @Lancelot, получилось решить проблему?

Comment: TrustManager остался на данный момент, с сертификатами не получилось ещё разобраться.

Comment: @Lancelot, можете отметить ответ как правильный, если он вам помог?

Comment: Тяжело его назвать окончательно правильным, но думаю кому-нибудь он пригодится и когда-нибудь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего дело в том, что http - незашифрованный поток, а https - зашифрованный, тобишь сэйфти. 
Таким образом, если вы хотите работать с https, то необходимо брать [Http**s**URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html), а не [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

**UPD:**
[image: rustack]

Давайте тогда разбираться на конкретном примере, какой сайт вы пытаетесь открыть? Потому что, как видно из картинки, заголовки видны даже у https.

Comment: Хорошая идея, я попробовал, но всё равно ссылку с https ставит null

Comment: @Lancelot, добавил дополнительное описание.

Comment: У вас осталось ещё желание помочь?